# How to apply '/' in every element of the matrix? Matlab

Tags: matlab

`A = [1 2; 3 4]`

I want to apply 1/n in every element of the matrix A, so that it can look like

`A = [1/1 1/2; 1/3 1/4]`

I know I can do this by using 'for loop' but I need to code it in a concise way.
How can I do this without using index of row and column?

Answer (score 3):

[Right-array dvision](https://www.mathworks.com/help/fixedpoint/ref/rdivide.html)

```
A = [1 2; 3 4]
A = 1 ./ A
```

---

```
A =

   1   2
   3   4

A =

   1.00000   0.50000
   0.33333   0.25000
```

Comment: This was useful, but my code is more complicated..I found out that I can use arrayfun so thank you!

Comment: Ok, good that you found your answer already. The next time try to be a bit more specific about your problem in the description, and people might be able to give you more useful answers.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, I think the problem is that OP expected that 1 / A was a good and easily explainable proxy for some other problem he had.  I don't think arrayfun is a very good idea for solving the problem of 1/A as stated in the question.   If OPs original problem is a good fit for SO, then I think the best would be to create a new self answered question.  (He could also technically edit this question, but that would invalidate this answer)

Comment: @visibleman, agree with you on all counts. Thanks for taking the time.